# LevelDB Benchmark in case of Huge Data Volume

Tags: benchmarking, leveldb

In case of huge amount of data is stored in LevelDB, say 1TB data size and 1G records (1K bytes per record), is there a benchmark for random record query and random write?
We want to know if LevelDB performance degrades while DB size gets larger and larger.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I'm interested in that too.

Comment: @EvyatarSegal Please refer to the pasted snapshot about random read and write of LevelDB. That's all I found.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Random Read, Random Write Metrics]
[image: Random Read Performance]

Some data I found about leveldb